# DefaultMessageListenerContainer managed with JMX + ActiveMQ Multiple Consumers on a Single Queue

Tags: java, spring, jms, jmx

Say you have two Spring `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` listening on the same Queue (ActiveMQ for example), started in different VMs.

Send 1 000 000 messages in. After 500 000 of messages you want the rest of them to be handled by only one `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, BUT without calling destroy or shutdown on the other (since you might needed it in the future - and must keep it manageable with JMX). The numbers are just for example here and should be ignored, could be replaced with - "after some time, after some messages, etc etc"

This sounds easy : call stop on the other `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. Wrong, since messages are dispatched in a Round Robin fashion and they get registered with the Consumer.

Add transaction support and throw an error in the second `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` every time a messages comes in, it will be rolled-back and taken (round-robin) by the first one. Wrong again, the messages somehow registers with the consumer, not allowing the first `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` to take the message.

Even if you you shutdown/destroy the first DMLC - the message is NOT consumed by the other DMLC. They ARE Consumed only if I kill the JVM that the now shutdown/destroyed DMLC was running in.

My Solution so far : Because of the `Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` messages are taken out from the Queue before they enter the onMessage method in the MessageListener of the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. In the `MessageListener` implement `SessionAwareMessageListener` and re-send a fresh copy of the message with the same payload. 
But this looks really dirty - I wish I could do it more in a "JMS"-ish way.

Comment: well, can I "un-register" the the messages from a particular Consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully grasp this part: "[the messages] get registered with the Consumer". Do you mean that ActiveMQ decides which listener to send it to? What exactly happens when you call "stop" on the DMLC?

I don't know if this is going to overcome your difficulties, but here's an idea: message selectors in DMLCs are **live**: you can change them any time and they are effective immediately. Perhaps try changing the message selector to "FALSE"; all cached messages should finish processing and new ones should stop coming.

Comment: In fact I forgot to mention that I have tried Message Selectors as well - it does not work. What happens when you invoke stop() on the MDLC? Here is an example: both DMLC are started and each inside it's onMessage method outputs the payload. I send two messages in , the output is "1111" in one DMLC and "2222" in the other. I stop one DMLC and send two more, the output is "3333" in the first and nothing in the second. I start the second : output is "4444". Hope that's clear

Comment: @Eugene Can you explain more then, as indicated in the first part of my answer?

Comment: It seems that internally the ActiveMQ with it's default Round Robin Policy somehow registers each message with a particular Consumer and keeps this order. You see what happens when you have multiple consumers for a Queue is not specified in the JMS. It is up to the provider to decide. I will test this again on Tibco EMS today and post the result

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for explanation. Now I think your question is misdirected: you should rather ask it in the context of ActiveMQ and **not** Spring DMLC. It seems like you did all you could do with DMLC.

Comment: Thank You actually. Yup, I know, I just thought that may be the registry with the consumer and message happens somewhere in the JMS Headers and you could clean it... Well anyhow thx for your help.